# If $y = 6x\ln(x)$, find the following . $y''$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, chain-rule

If $y = 6x\ln(x)$, find the following:  $y''$

Calculated $y'$ to: $$\frac{6x}{x} + 6\ln(x)$$

Isn't $$y'' =  6x(1) + \frac{x(6)}{x^2} + \frac{6}{x}$$

I don't understand why that is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  are almost there. Your $y'$ is correct. You need to simplify it further, to get:
$$y'=6+6\ln x$$ and so we get
$$y''=0+\frac{6}{x}=\frac{6}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

You asked for what was wrong with your work, and this is an attempt to explain that.

You say: calculated $y'$ to: $$\frac{6x}{x} + 6\ln(x)$$

The derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\frac{-1}{x^2}$

Therefore, if you don't simplify $\frac{6x}{x}$ to $6$ like the others have done here, you will get:

$$y'' =  6 (1) \bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg) + 6 (x)\bigg(\frac{-1}{x^2}\bigg) + \frac{6}{x}$$

$$=  \bigg(\frac{6}{x}\bigg) - \bigg(\frac{6}{x}\bigg) + \frac{6}{x}$$

$$y'' = \frac{6}{x}$$

Comment: The op asked why something didn't work and I pointed out the error. The other answers give their own solutions and don't help the op know what happened. That's the reason for the extra weird solution. Do you think that's useless? I thought this site was to help people, not a competitive problem solving site.

Comment: user1952500 No, your answer is **not useless**.  I can understand your point. Thanks for your time spent to comment. I will make a teeny weeny edit of some sort to your answer, so I can remove my downvote (and upvote, (and I'll delete my comment too).

Comment: Thanks @amWhy for the edit. I'll make it clear from the next time onwards.

Comment: No worries;  the only reason I edited your post is that, once a person upvotes or downvotes a question, it can only be retracted when the post has been edited.  I didn't want to edit your argument, I just wanted to make some sort of edit so I could retract my original downvote, and vote again $\uparrow$.

Answer (score 0):

$y' = 6(ln(x)+1))$

$y'' = \frac{6}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
y'=(6x/x)+6\log(x)=6+6\log(x)
$$

$$
y''=6/x
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use product rule to get $\displaystyle y' = 6\ln(x)+\frac{6x}{x}=6\ln(x)+6$

Then differentiate again to get $\displaystyle \boxed{y''=\frac{6}{x}}$.